# Couldn't find Message with 'id'=#<Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fbae5f12a78>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is params hash.

```
 {"message_id"=>"#<Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fbae5f12a78>",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

I have a scenario like messages has many comments. When i try to edit the commets of a message i get a error

```
"Couldn't find Message with 'id'=#<Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fbae5f12a78>"
```

and my edit method is given below

```
def edit
    @message = Message.find(params[:message_id])
    # @message = Message.find(3)
    @comment = @message.comments.find(params[:id])  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`@message.comments` will return all of the comments from the `@message` you've located.

You need to either find the comment directly using the `params[:id]` you have:

```
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
```

Or, you need to selected it from your association query using a `where` condition:

```
@comment = @message.comments.where(id: params[:id])
```

Considering you have the specific `id` already, I'd just go with the first one. There's no benefit to using an association here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've somehow set the `message_id` parameter as `<Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fbae5f12a78>`

To fix it, you have to make sure that `message_id` is an actual integer:

```
{"message_id"=>"5", "id"=>"1"}
```

---

Specifically, why are you even getting this error?

It looks like you're using [`nested routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), which means that you'd typically access a resource by passing the route with the appropriate id's: `url.com/messages/1/comments/2`

Oh I get it.

**You need to fix your path**:

```
<%= link_to "Edit Comment", message_comments_path(message, comment) %>
```

What you've done is passed `@messages`, which is equal to `Message.all` or something. You need the individual `message` record passed to your path.